# Editable NSTextField in custom view of NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nsmenuitem, nsstatusitem

I have a subclassed NSView that I would like to contain an editable NSTextField, similar to Spotlight.

I am having significant difficult getting the text field to select and highlight. If I click quickly and rapidly over the editing area of the textfield, I can actually enter text, but it appears greyed out, as though I am adding text to a field of an app that is not foremost.

I have tried to get focus of the View's window using `viewDidMoveToWindow`, but apparently NSMenuItem's windows are carbon windows that don't handle keys very well.

Long  story short, what is a good way to go about making this work successfully? I know that Spotlight is a borderless window, but that is not suitable for my purposes.

Any and all suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, two things are common consensus:

(1) If you find yourself looking for ways to subclass a built-in UI element for special the chances are that you're doing something wrong, or at very least, there is a better way to do what you're trying to do.

(2) The reason to follow the interface guidelines is to be more future-compatible. There is no guarantee that a sub-classed UI element will be compatible with future versions of the OS.

Brass Tacks - subclassing UI elements is generally not advised.

Comment: So how did you solve the problem? You were clearly not doing something Apple does not recommend - you were merely trying to replicate how Spotlight works, as I understand things at the moment. NSView is a very generic "UI class" that in my view is MEANT to be subclassed. What if you want to create a pulsating status-bar item, or something like what Apple does with the Airport status-bar item. Your statement that UI classes should not be subclassed is too broad and not really justifiable. The point being, how else would you accomplish the functionality you wanted, and how did you?

Comment: What are you talking about? Sub-classed UI elements not being compatible with future versions of the OS? That's the weirdest thing I've ever heard. Every control in the OS is a subclassed UI element! The whole reason for adding an extendable NSView class is to have your own custom views. And I agree with Dev, you were not doing something Apple does not recommend. In fact Apple highly recommends you create custom views where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Matt Gemmell's MAAttachedWindow.

http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass

Comment: Yes, I am a long-time user of Gemmell's source & examples. Great resource. However, as I said above, I'm not really interested in borderless windows - I'm trying to avoid additional windows. If I have to, I'll emulate NSMenu within a borderless NSWindow, but that is highly undesirable; its very hacky and not future-proof at all.

Comment: Everything to do with NSView is future proof. I think you're either not describing the problem clearly or don't have a clearer picture of what you want to do. Either way, please elaborate as to what exactly you're trying to do as what you're saying is 100% future proof. That's the whole idea behind custom controls, unless you were relying on private API.